NLB and VPC link for api endpoint testing
My requirement is to test the api endpoints.
e.g. https://dev-alb.test.app/abc-svc/v1/healthcheck
I am able to get 200 response when I hit it in browser. In this case, my alb is public as its dev environment.
Now I want to test same thing in prod environment but my alb is private. So, can not browse this endpoint directly.
In this case, I have created NLB targeting my internal alb. And integrated vpc endpoint resource. In api gateway, created REST api. But not able to achieve the requirement.
What will be the prerequisites and endpoint in method.
https://prod-alb.test.app/abc-svc/v1/healthcheck this is my production env endpoint. http://prod-nlb.test.app is my dns of nlb.
I have allowed all the traffic in inbound rule of private alb. Also, added alb as a target for NLB.
What would be my endpoint in method configuration of api gateway

Could create a jump host to do the testing
